# Android Retrofit 2 get single list string value

Tags: android, json, string, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit 2 on Android Studio to get list string no names from WORDSAPI SYNONYMS.

I got JSON from

> https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com/words/go/synonyms?mashape-key={my-key}

----JSON----------

```
{
    "word": "go",
    "synonyms": [
        "proceed",
        "run",
        "depart",
        "go away",
        "function",
        ...,
        "get",
        "plump",
        "extend",
        "fit"
    ]
}
```

Can you help me how to create **Call, SynonymsList and get list string of Synonyms** in Android code??
It makes me confusing because it is different to Array JSON!!

Thank you!

Comment: show your existing **code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

> ApiClient:

```
public class ApiClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static final String SERVER_BASE_URL = "https://wordsapiv1.p.mashape.com";

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(SERVER_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

> ApiInterface :

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("/words/go/synonyms")
    Call<ResponseBody> getDataFromServer(@Query("mashape-key") String mashape_key);

}
```

> MainActivity -> onCreate() :

```
ServerData serverData;

ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.getDataFromServer(mashape_key);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                try {
                    Log.e("~~~~~ response", response.body().string());
                    String response = responsebody.body().string();
                    serverData = gson.fromJson(response, ServerData.class);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {


            }
        });
```

> ServerData :

```
public class ServerData {

    @SerializedName("word")
    private String word;

    @SerializedName("synonyms")
    private ArrayList<String> synonyms;

}
```

Comment: I use response.body().string(); --- it showed all things of that JSON like -- {"word":"go","synonyms":["proceed","run","depart","go away"} --- How to get all values in "synonyms" and set it to String[].. Thank you!!

Comment: you can use serverData.getsynonyms() , first add getter -setter to ServerData class.

Comment: I did but it return null.

Comment: I got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your Pojo class :-

```
public class WordsObj {    
  String word;
  List<String> synonyms;
}
```

RetrofitInterface :-

```
@Get("yOURuRL")
Call<WordsObj> getWords();
```

Your call :-

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("base_url")
            .build();

Call<WordsObj> call_for_words = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class).getWords();
```

Then make your call :-

```
call_for_words.enqueue(...) // for asynchronous
```

Or,

```
call_for_words.execute()   // for synchornous
```